# Generic NamedTuple in Python 3.6

Tags: python, generics, python-3.6, typing

I'm trying to create a generic version of a NamedTuple, as follows:

```
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

class Group(NamedTuple, Generic[T1, T2]):
    key: T1
    group: List[T2]

g = Group(1, [""])  # expecting type to be Group[int, str]
```

However, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
```

I'm not sure how else to achieve what I'm trying to do here, or if this might be a bug in the typing mechanism on some level.

Comment: You may further elaborate, in which respect you intend to generalize NamedTuple, which is pretty general in my opinion. From your code snippet I can't recognize...

Comment: The special `NamedTuple` doesn't support *any other base classes*. Full stop. The `NamedTuple` base class delegates all use to a metaclass that will run `collections.namedtuple()` with a small amount of customisation, which means that the resulting class *only ever inherits from `tuple`*. This is a wider problem with `NamedTuple`, not limited to `Generic`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So this is a metaclass conflict since in python 3.6 the typing `NamedTuple` and `Generic` use different metaclasses (`typing.NamedTupleMeta` and `typing.GenericMeta`), which python can't handle. I'm afraid there is no solution to this, other than to subclass from `tuple` and manually initialise the values:

```
T1 = TypeVar("T1")
T2 = TypeVar("T2")

class Group(tuple, Generic[T1, T2]):

    key: T1
    group: List[T2]

    def __new__(cls, key: T1, group: List[T2]):
        self = tuple.__new__(cls, (key, group))
        self.key = key
        self.group = group
        return self            

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'Group(key={self.key}, group={self.group})'

Group(1, [""])  # --> Group(key=1, group=[""])
```

---

Due to PEPs [560](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#whatsnew37-pep560) and [563](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0563/) this is fixed in python 3.7:

```
Python 3.7.0b2 (v3.7.0b2:b0ef5c979b, Feb 28 2018, 02:24:20) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import annotations
>>> from typing import *
>>> T1 = TypeVar("T1")
>>> T2 = TypeVar("T2")
>>> class Group(NamedTuple, Generic[T1, T2]):
...     key: T1
...     group: List[T2]
...
>>> g: Group[int, str] = Group(1, [""])
>>> g
Group(key=1, group=[''])
```

Of course in python 3.7 you can just use a dataclass which are less lightweight (and mutable) but serve similar purposes.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, astuple
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, List

T1 = TypeVar('T1')
T2 = TypeVar('T2')

@dataclass
class Group(Generic[T1, T2]):

     # this stores the data like a tuple, but isn't required
     __slots__ = ("key", "group")

     key: T1
     group: List[T2]

     # if you want to be able to unpack like a tuple...
     def __iter__(self):
          yield from astuple(self)


g: Group[int, str] = Group(1, ['hello', 'world'])
k, v = g
print(g)
```

---

How well type checkers handle my solution / yours in python 3.7 though I haven't checked. I suspect it may not be seamless.

---

## Edit

I found another solution -- make a new metaclass

```
import typing
from typing import *

class NamedTupleGenericMeta(typing.NamedTupleMeta, typing.GenericMeta):
    pass


class Group(NamedTuple, Generic[T1,T2], metaclass=NamedTupleGenericMeta):

    key: T1
    group: List[T2]


Group(1, ['']) # --> Group(key=1, group=[''])
```

Comment: The second solution looks nice, but unfortunately it doesn't fully work for type hinting:`g: Group[int, str] = Group(1, [""])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Ah ok. What if you swap the metaclasses bases around? How did the first one go?

Comment: You still can't *use* the `Generic[...]` hint in `NamedTuple` subclasses, because due to the very same metaclass conflict the newly generated named tuple class won't have the `__class_getitem__` hook needed to make concrete hints like `Group[str, int]` work. That's because the `NamedTuple` metaclass returns a new class object with only `tuple` as a base class, not `Generic`, and the requisite `__parameters__` attribute on the class that records the available typevars is completely gone.

Comment: @MartijnPieters fair point, but fixed with `from __future__ import annotations`

Comment: Please make that more explicit in your answer, because you need that compiler switch in *all* modules that use that subclass.

Comment: also mypy complains "Generic tuple types not supported"

Comment: and with the dataclass + `__iter__` method workaround, when you do a destructuring assignment the resulting vars are `Any` typed due to limitation of `astuple` (this issue https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5152) But I guess this is the best we can do for the foreseeable future... the relevant issue for supporting generic namedtuples in mypy has been open and unfixed for 5 years now: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/685

Comment: downvoting because the first option doesn't retain the immutability of `NamedTuple` and the third option doesn't retain its type safety when unpacking

Comment: In python 3.9, OP's original code now breaks on declaration of the class, even if the class goes unused, with the error `TypeError: Multiple inheritance with NamedTuple is not supported`

Comment: Also, on Python 3.7+, `typing.GenericMeta` doesn't seem to exist.  https://github.com/mkdocstrings/mkdocstrings/issues/2  .

Comment: yup, seems they broke it. My suggestion is to use a `dataclass(frozen=True)` with `__slots__` if you need them. Still, so annoying!