# Can you give an example for a NESTED TypedDict in class notation?

Tags: settings, python-3.8, typeddict

I want to have typed settings and came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409117/what-are-the-main-differences-of-namedtuple-and-typeddict-in-python-mypy) answer and TypedDict but could not get it working with nested structures.

Assuming the following dict, how can I best add typing?

```
{
    "global": {
        "region": "eu-central-1",
    },
    "env": {
        "dev": {
            "name": "dev.local",
        },
        "prod": {
            "name": "prod.world",
        }
    }
}
```

P.S.: I would also be interested, how to do that with data classes, if you have the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```py
from typing import TypedDict

class Env(TypedDict):
    name: str

class Region(TypedDict):
    region: str

class EnvDescr(TypedDict):
    global: Region
    dev: Env
    prod: Env
```