# Make a Union of strings to be used as possible dictionary keys

Tags: python, types, pylance, pyright

I have some Python 3.7 code and I am trying to add types to it. One of the types I want to add is actually an `Union` of several possible strings:

```
from typing import Union, Optional, Dict

PossibleKey = Union["fruits", "cars", "vegetables"]
PossibleType = Dict[PossibleKey, str]

def some_function(target: Optional[PossibleType] = None):
  if target:
    all_fruits = target["fruits"]
    print(f"I have {all_fruits}")
```

The problem here is that Pyright complains about `PossibleKey`. It says:

> "fruits is not defined"

I would like to get Pyright/Pylance to work.

I have checked the `from enum import Enum` module from another SO answer, but if I try that I end up with more issues since I am actually dealing with a `Dict[str, Any]` and not an `Enum`.

What is the proper Pythonic way of representing my type?

Comment: "but if I try that I end up with more issues since I am actually dealing with a Dict[str, Any] and not an Enum" Exactly which answer did you refer to, and exactly how did you try to implement it? We can only tell you what is wrong with code that you actually show to us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 dictionary with known keys typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44225788/python-3-dictionary-with-known-keys-typing)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53409117/what-are-the-main-differences-of-namedtuple-and-typeddict-in-python-mypy

Comment: Is the dict guaranteed to have *all* three keys, or does it just guarantee that it has some subset of the three as its keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Pyright` error disappears if you define `PossibleKey` as `Enum` as below.
This requires only one line change to the original code.
If there is some issue with using Enum, please elaborate on that.

```py
from typing import Union, Optional, Dict
from enum import Enum

PossibleKey = Enum("PossibleKey", ["fruits", "cars", "vegetables"])
PossibleType = Dict[PossibleKey, str]

def some_function(target: Optional[PossibleType] = None):
  if target:
    all_fruits = target["fruits"]
    print(f"I have {all_fruits}")
```

Answer (score 8):

`"fruits"` is not a type (hint), but `Literal["fruits"]` is.

```
from typing import Union, Literal

PossibleKey = Union[Literal["fruits"], Literal["cars"], Literal["vegetables"]]
```

or the much shorter version,

```
PossibleKey = Literal["fruits", "cars", "vegetables"]
```

Or, as you mentioned, define an `Enum` populated by the three values.

```
from enum import Enum


class Key(Enum):
    Fruits = "fruits"
    Cars = "cars"
    Vegetables = "vegetables"


def some_function(target: Optional[PossibleType] = None):
    if target:
        all_fruits = target[Key.Fruits]
        print(f"I have {all_fruits}")
```

(However, just because `target` is not `None` doesn't necessarily mean it actually *has* `"fruits"` as a key, only that *doesn't* have a key other than `Key.Fruits`, `Key.Cars`, or `Key.Vegetables`.)

Comment: Unfortunately `Literal` was introduced only in Python 3.8, and I am stuck with 3.7.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Literal