# Generic NamedTuple in python 3.7

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, namedtuple

What is the correct way to define a **Generic** **NamedTuple**  in using the typing module **python 3.7**?

I can define

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, NamedTuple

T = TypeVar("T")

class C(Generic[T], NamedTuple):
    """NameTuple and Generic ???"""
    x: T

c = C(1)
print(c)  # prints "C(x=1)", as expected
```

However, I cannot use the `C[T]` as a type hint:

```py
# raises TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
def f(c: C[int]):
    print("from f:", c)
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, the metaclass conflict mentioned in [Generic NamedTuple in Python 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50530959/generic-namedtuple-in-python-3-6) does not apply to python 3.7, where `__class_getitem__` is used as detailed in *PEP 560*. It seems that `typing.NamedTupleMeta` calls [collections.namedtuple()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f45813df52207ae870fda86475976a9b42857592/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L460) which uses `type(...)` with no other base classe than `tuple`. I don't see a workaround - hence the question here... (I don't think it's a duplicate)

Comment: @MartijnPieters this doesn't look like a duplicate ^^^

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: Yes, Python 3.7 added `__class_getitem__`, but the problem is still the same; the metaclasses between `NamedTuple` and `Generic` conflict. The `NamedTuple` metaclass will always return a subclass of `tuple`, so the `Generic` base is lost, and so no `__class_getitem__` method is available. Python 3.7 *does not fix the problem*.

Comment: @JoelBerkeley: and the answer on the dupe has a work-around that works just as well in Python 3.7.

Comment: @vpquant: put differently: sorry, you are mistaken. The metaclass conflict still applies.